# Recursive Python Function not Returning Data

Tags: python, pandas, recursion

I have a recursive function

```
def boost_test(frame, iteration, max_iteration):
    if iteration < max_iteration:
        print iteration, max_iteration
        # get predictions
        iteration += 1
        boost_test(frame, iteration, max_iteration)
    elif iteration == max_iteration:
        print 'return frame', iteration, max_iteration, frame.columns
        #print frame
        return frame
```

I can run it like this:

```
testF = pd.DataFrame([1,2])
testF.columns = ['hello']
n = boost_test(testF, 0, 5)
```

Here is the output:
    0 5
    1 5
    2 5
    3 5
    4 5
    return frame 5 5 Index([u'hello'], dtype='object')

So, it looks like everything is correct.  But if it doesn't look like the function is actually returning a frame.

When I try
    n.head()

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

I'm at a loss for why it isn't returning the dataframe.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to `return` in all execution paths of the recursive function, so the `if` block should end with `return boost_test(frame, iteration, max_iteration)`. Otherwise, that section will return the default value of `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
boost_test(frame, iteration, max_iteration)
```

Here, you make the recursive call, but do nothing with the result. You need to explicitly `return` the value for it to make its way back up the call stack.

Comment: Thanks. Feel like I should have figured that out!